# Off topic, but only because of setting

Tags: discussion

[Co-leader quit in anger, now says "it doesn't count": how to enforce](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35868/co-leader-quit-in-anger-now-says-it-doesnt-count-how-to-enforce)

The above question was closed due to being Off Topic.  The off topic parts of the question appear to be the use of the word "teacher/advisor" and a comment by the OP stating that she is still in school.

However, the situation itself is very generic.  If we substituted the word "manager" for "teacher/advisor" then we have an otherwise common issue that people face when sharing leadership responsibility and dealing with the problems of personality conflicts.  Further, in this particular case the OP had to apply for and be "hired" for the job.

My question is: should a question actually be closed simply due to setting (school vs office building) or should questions which are also commonly faced within a traditional workplace setting be on topic?

Comment: It's difficult. In a real workplace situation, you could recommend talking to HR, discussing it with your immediate manager during your weekly 1-on-1 meeting, etc. But these clearly don't apply to someone on a club in High School. Pretty much anything we could respond with might help with some vague future reader in some generic way, but wouldn't help with the real OP's question. I think the question has very low value here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is: should a question actually be closed simply due to setting or should questions which are also commonly faced within a "workplace" setting be on topic?

As a user with 4500 reputation you can do a lot of things to help with situations like this.

- You can edit questions to make them more on topic (I edited [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35905/2322) slightly this morning for exactly these reasons)
- You can vote to reopen
- You can post on meta to discuss the question

Questions which get edited after closing are automatically added to the [reopen community vote queue](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/).

I would encourage you to take advantage of the other community moderation tools as well.

Comment: Your point was well taken and I modified the question to remove the "school" references.